# C++ I have some seryous issues with inheritance when derived and base class have different types of parameters, like shown below:

Tags: c++, class, parameters, constructor, operator-overloading

Im a newbie in c++ and recently discovered classes;

I learned about constructors, overloading operators, the rule of three and right now i tried to learn inheritance.

I created 4 classes: 2 parents, 2 childs, but i occured some problems in class parent1

This is class parent1:

```
class parent1{

protected:
    float slr;
    int age;
    char *name;
    void set_new_name(char ch[10001]);

public:

    parent1()
    {
        slr=0.0;
        age=0;
        name=NULL;
    }

    parent1(char ch[10001], float sl, int ag)
    {
        slr=sl;
        age=ag;
        set_new_name(ch);
    }

    parent1(const parent1 &p1)
    {
        char temp[10001];
        strcpy(temp,p1.name);

        if(name != NULL)
            delete[] name;
        set_new_name(temp);
        slr=p1.slr;
        age=p1.age;
    }

    parent1 &operator=(const parent1 &p1)
    {
        /// same lines as in copy constructor above
        return *this;
    }

    char* get_name() const;
    void print1();

    ~parent1()
    {
        delete[] name;
    }
};
```

This is his child class, child1:

```
class child1 : public parent1{

protected:

    int id;
    void set_id(int j);

public:

    child1(): parent1()
    {
        set_id(0);
    }

    child1(char ch[10001],float sl, int ag, int j): parent1(ch,sl,ag)
    {
        set_id(j);
    }

    child1(const child1 &p2): parent1(p2)
    {
        set_id(p2.get_id());
    }

    child1 &operator=(const child1 &p2)
    {
        set_id(p2.get_id());
        parent1::operator=(p2);
    }

    int get_id() const;
    void print2();
};
```

There is class parent 2:

```
class parent2{

protected:

    char *name1;
    char *name2;
    void set_new_name1(char ch1[10001]);
    void set_new_name2(char ch2[14]);

public:

    parent2()
    {
        name1=NULL;
        name2=NULL;
    }

    parent2(char ch1[10001], char ch2[14])
    {
        set_new_name1(ch1);
        set_new_name2(ch2);
    }

    parent2(const parent2 &p3)
    {
        char temp2[10001];
        strcpy(temp2,p3.name1);
        if(name1 !=NULL)
            delete[] name1;
        set_new_name1(temp2);

        /// .. . same lines as above, this time for name2 and p3.name2
    }

    parent2 &operator=(const parent2 &p3)
    {
        /// .. same lines as in copy constructor above

        return *this;

    }

    char* get_name1() const;
    char* get_name2() const;
    void print3();

    ~parent2()
    {
        delete[] name1;
        delete[] name2;
    }

};
```

And there is his child, child 2:

```
class child2: public parent2{

protected:
    char *job;
    void set_new_job(char ch3[15]);

public:

    child2(): parent2()
    {
       job=NULL;
    }

    child2(char ch1[10001], char ch2[10001],char ch3[11]): parent2(ch1,ch2)
    {
        set_new_job(ch3);
    }

    child2(const child2 &p4): parent2(p4)
    {
        char temp6[11];
        strcpy(temp6, p4.job);
        if(job != NULL)
            delete[] job;
        set_new_job(temp6);
    }

    child2 &operator=(const child2 &p4)
    {
        /// same lines as in copy constructor
        parent2::operator=(p4);
    }

    char* get_job() const;
    void print4();

    ~child2()
    {
        delete[] job;
    }
};
```

As u can see up here, class parent1 have 3 types of parameters ( one float, one int and one char*).

*Nonte: set_ functions works ok, get_functions just return class parametes (also works ok) , print functions just print classes parameters ( ex: cout << name1; also works fine)*

The problem is that this code refuse to work when i create the objects in main.
First i thought it is operator= being overloaded to many times, bit it turned out to be the float parameter from parent1
There is the main:

```
char ch[10001]="my name", ch1[10001]="my name 1", ch2[14]="my name 2", ch3[11]="some code";
    int ag=10;
    float sl=10.1;

    parent1 o1;
    o1=parent1(ch,sl,ag);
    o1.print1();
    parent1 o2(o1);
    o2.print1();

    child1 o3;
    o3=child1(ch,sl,ag,3);
    o3.print2();

    child1 o4;
    o4=child1(ch,sl,ag,6);
    o4.print2();
    o4=o3;
    o4.print2();

    parent2 o5;
    o5=parent2(ch1,ch2);
    o5.print3();

    child2 o6(ch1,ch2,ch3);
    o6.print4();
```

The only things that seems to make it run are:

- deleting the float parameter from parent1;
- deleting the last class ; (i really don't know why the last class affect the program)
- creating the last object like this :  child2 o6(ch1,ch2,ch3);  , which is frustrating because it should work like the others;

*I know the code i sheared is very long, but **Please** , **Help me** to understand what i need to do to solve this stupid bug !*

Comment: A personal rule: if a class has a copy assignment operator, it should not be derived from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least 3 issues in the code that will lead to a crash/undefined behavior.

First:

```
parent1(const parent1 &p1)
{
    char temp[10001];
    strcpy(temp,p1.name);

    if(name != NULL)             // name isn't initialized yet,
        delete[] name;           // these 2 lines shouldn't be here
    set_new_name(temp);
    slr=p1.slr;
    age=p1.age;
}
```

Second: (these ones are reported by the compiler when warnings are enabled)

```
child1 &operator=(const child1 &p2)
{
    set_id(p2.get_id());
    parent1::operator=(p2);
    return *this;               // this line is missing
}
```

Third:

```
child2 &operator=(const child2 &p4)
{
    char temp7[11];
    strcpy(temp7, p4.job);
    if(job != NULL)
        delete[] job;
    set_new_job(temp7);
    parent2::operator=(p4);
    return *this;               // this line is missing
}
```

The `return` statement is not "inherited". Each function that's supposed to return something must do so.

With these changes the code runs:

```
my name
my name
3
6
3
my name 1
my name 2
some code
```

([Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VH8Hft0igeItpgdQ))

Some additional improvement notes:

An array like `char ch[10001]` can't really be a function argument in C++. When it's used as an argument it silently decays to `char *`. So you might as well replace all `char ch[10001]` with `const char* ch` (and better yet, `std::string`), to avoid confusion.

Also, there's no point in allocating a `temp` array. You can just directly do `set_new_name(p1.name)`:

```
parent1(const parent1 &p1)
{
    set_new_name(p1.name);
    slr=p1.slr;
    age=p1.age;
}
```

It would be prudent to invest some time in getting familiar with a Debugger. It's all but impossible to make a working application without debugging it. And enable compiler warnings. With GCC use `-Wall -Wextra`, with MSVC - `/W4`.

Here's an example of the code using `std::string`. Thanks to `std::string` we can follow the rule of 0:

```
class parent1 {

protected:
  float slr = 0;
  int age = 0;
  string name;
  void set_new_name(string const &ch) { name = ch; }

public:
  parent1() {}

  parent1(string const &name, float slr, int age)
      : slr(slr), age(age), name(name) {}

  string const &get_name() const { return name; }
  void print1();
};

void parent1::print1() { cout << get_name() << '\n'; }

class child1 : public parent1 {

protected:
  int id = 0;
  void set_id(int j) { id = j; }

public:
  child1() : parent1() {}

  child1(string const &name, float sl, int ag, int j)
      : parent1(name, sl, ag), id(j) {}

  int get_id() const { return id; }
  void print2();
};

void child1::print2() { cout << get_id() << '\n'; }

class parent2 {

protected:
  string name1;
  string name2;

  void set_new_name1(string const &ch) { name1 = ch; }
  void set_new_name2(string const &ch) { name2 = ch; }

public:
  parent2() {}

  parent2(string const &name1, string const &name2)
      : name1(name1), name2(name2) {}

  string const &get_name1() const { return name1; }
  string const &get_name2() const { return name2; }
  void print3();
};

void parent2::print3() {
  cout << get_name1() << '\n';
  cout << get_name2() << '\n';
}

class child2 : public parent2 {

protected:
  string job;
  void set_new_job(string const &ch) { job = ch; }

public:
  child2() : parent2() {}

  child2(string const &name1, string const &name2, string const &job)
      : parent2(name1, name2), job(job) {}

  string const &get_job() const { return job; }
  void print4();
};

void child2::print4() { cout << get_job() << '\n'; }
```

And this works [equally well](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2CjPqxhpHofm2EWR).